# How can the two sides in syrian conflict be defined?

Tags: syria, civil-war

After somewhat of research, I have found that there are many sides of the syrian conflict.For example

- Attack on specific side of streets occupied by specific tribes by military shows a **shia vs sunni** conflict.
- The most widely considered(but not 100% true) **asad regime vs activists**
- The two superpowers driving the country, **US vs Russia**. A fight for control over arab.
- What asad regime itself says, **asad vs terrorists**.
- And something that's going on, **Military vs common people**.

Which of these are true? Which is most influencing the battleground?

Comment: I'd say one of the defining characteristics of the Syrian conflict is how many more sides than "two" there are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Which of these are true?" - The answer is, ALL of them, to more or less extent.

Take a look at a brief summary of engaged forces on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syrian_Civil_War), just for the first approximation.

---

"Which is most influencing the battleground?" - depends.

Purely numbers wise, it's Assad vs everyone (again, the #s are on Wiki)

In terms of effectiveness, it's Shia vs Sunni, since the most effective forces are Basj/Hezbollah on one side and imported Sunni Jihadists on the other.

Comment: "Imported Sunni Jihadists" that's not true. ***MOST*** of the opposition is actually Syrian people who raised armies. (P.S I live in Damascus).